# header back button not showing up in stack screen

Tags: react-native

I have tab navigator, and one of the tab holds a stack navigator:

```
<Tab.Screen 
    name="Create" 
    component={createFlowStack} 
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: ' ',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
        <Ionicons name="md-add-circle" size={size} color={color} />
      ),
    }}
    
/>
```

Within the "create flow stack", a user goes through a flow to create a post. Picking an image, adding a caption, etc. I have a back button that I coded, but for ux reasons, want to remove the back button and display the back button in the header, like this:

[image]

So I added this code into the "create flow stack":

```
<CreateStack.Screen 
     name="GainScreenshot" 
     component={GainScreenshot} 
     options=  {{
     headerBackTitle: "back"
}}/>
```

But nothing shows up:

[image]

I want to get rid of the blue back button in the screen, and replace it with the back button in the header. How can I achieve this? Is the problem that the create stack is nested within the tab stack?

Comment: Haven't been able to solve this issue still. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a custom header. It seems I'm three years late but in case someone else needs it, you need to use a function inside the options of the screen or inside screenoptions in the stack depending on your case use, like this:

```
 <Stack.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeScreen}
  options={{
    headerLeft: (props) => (
      <MyButton
        {...props}
        onPress={() => {
          // Do something
        }}
      />
    ),
  }}
/>
```

there are many ways to achieve custom headers all the info can be found in the docs: [React-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#headerleft).

i hope it solves someone's problems!